# Broadcasting events mannually in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I was looking for the similar implementation of `$broadcast` and `$on` in Angular 5. I found out that, we can create custom service, to do this job using `broadcaster`.

I have two parallel components. In which I want to listen to the change event. Whenever parent trigger event these two components should listen and do some processing. But I am trying this approach but, either only one `Component1` or `Component2` listens to the event.

**Broadcaster.ts**

```
interface BroadcastEvent {
  key: any;
  data?: any;
}

@Injectable()
export class Broadcaster {
  private _eventBus: Subject<BroadcastEvent>;

  constructor() {
    this._eventBus = new Subject<BroadcastEvent>();
  }

  broadcast(key: any, data?: any) {
    this._eventBus.next({key, data});
  }

  on<T>(key: any): Observable<T> {
    return this._eventBus.asObservable()
      .filter(event => event.key === key)
      .map(event => <T>event.data);
  }
}
```

**Component1.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-Component1',
  templateUrl: './Component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit{

  @Input() data: Student;

  constructor(private broadcaster: Broadcaster) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {


    this.broadcaster.on<string>('selectStudent').subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Component 1");
    });
  }
```

**Component2.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-Component2',
  templateUrl: './Component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Component2.component.css']
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit{

  @Input() data: Student;

  constructor(private broadcaster: Broadcaster) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {


    this.broadcaster.on<string>('selectStudent').subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Component 2");
    });
  }
```

**Parent Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-Component1',
  templateUrl: './Parent .component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Parent .component.css']
})
export class Parent implements OnInit{

  data: Student;

  constructor(private broadcaster: Broadcaster) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(data) {
   this.data = data;
   this.broadcaster.broadcast('selectStudent');
   console.log("Parent Component");
 }
```

**Parent Html**

```
<app-Component1 [data]="data"> </app-Component1>
<app-Component2 [data]="data"> </app-Component2>
```

**Output**

```
Parent Component

Component 1
```

**Output**

```
Parent Component

Component 2
```

Is anything I am missing? Why are all components not listening event?

Comment: Show the parent's template/markup, maybe there's some typo there when you add those child components.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler Updated question. Parent template just has two child components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out way given by angular website. Written one service to broadcast event and listen to the event.

**datachangedservice.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class DataChangedService {

    private dataChange = new Subject<Student>();

  dataChanged$ = this.dataChange.asObservable();

  dataChanged(data) {
    this.dataChange.next(data);
  }
}
```

**component1.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-Component1',
  templateUrl: './Component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit{

  @Input() data: Student;

  constructor(private broadcaster: DataChangedService) {    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.broadcaster.dataChanged$.subscribe( data => {
           // some code
     });        
  }
```

**parent.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-Component1',
  templateUrl: './Parent .component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Parent .component.css']
})
export class Parent implements OnInit{

  data: Student;

  constructor(private broadcaster: DataChangedService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(data) {
   this.broadcaster.dataChanged(data);
   console.log("Parent Component");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The is actually a better pattern available. If `component1` and `component2` are both children of the `parent` component you should implement `ngOnChanges` in both children comps.

**ngOnChanges**

> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.
>   Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

**component1.ts**

```
@Component({selector: 'comp1', template: `...`})
class Component1 implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  data: any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const dataChange = changes['data'];
    if (dataChange) {
      // do something with the updated data
    }
  }
}
```

**parent.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent', 
  template: `
    <comp1 [data]="data"></comp1>
    <comp2 [data]="data"></comp2>
})
class Component1 implements OnChanges {
  data: any;

  onClick() {
     // if you change the data here it will trigger
     // ngOnChanges in the child components
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't do this. Because I am changing data from child components as well, so the same method will get a call. I don't want that.