# Handle component1.onClick by invoking function in component2. Not parent/child components. Angular 5 and Rxjs

Tags: angular

I have tried numerous possible solutions that are all nearly the exact same solution using ReactiveX Observables in a shared service. I can trigger the change() function in the service but thats as far as I get...always. this.dataSource.next(param) does not trigger the Observable data$ in component2. One example solution I tried is in [Broadcasting events mannually in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981766/broadcasting-events-mannually-in-angular-5) . Please help.

```
.
.
Import { EventProxyService } from ‘event-proxy.service’
@Component({
       .
       .
       providers: [ EventProxyService ]
})
export class Component1 {
    constructor(private eventProxyService: EventProxyService){}
    onClick(){
        console.log(“onClick clicked”)
        this.eventProxyService.change(“1”)
    }
}

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
@Injectable()
export class EventProxyService {
    private dataSource = new Subject<any>()
    data$ = this.dataSource.asObservable()
    change(param: any) {
        console.log("in service", param)
        this.dataSource.next(param)
    }
}

Import { EventProxyService } from ‘event-proxy.service’
@Component({
.
.
    providers: [ EventProxyService ]
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
    constructor(private eventProxyService: EventProxyService){}
    ngOnInit() {

        this.eventProxyService.data$.subscribe((param: any) => {
            console.log("in jobs", param)
        })
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you are providing same service in two different components separately. Which will create two different objects of service and will use it for each service. So it is better always to provide services in root module or atleast in parent module for all the components going to use the service so that you will not run in this kind of issue.

Here to use it correctly provide `EventProxyService` in root module or parent module for all the components going to use the service. Please remove providers from both the component and provide the service in `App.module.ts` or parent module for both the components.

Your code will look something like this

```
.
.
@Component({
    .
    .
})
export class Component1 {
    constructor(private eventProxyService: EventProxyService){}
    onClick(){
        console.log(“onClick clicked”)
        this.eventProxyService.change(“1”)
    }
}

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
@Injectable()
export class EventProxyService {
    private dataSource = new Subject<any>()
    data$ = this.dataSource.asObservable()
    change(param: any) {
        console.log("in service", param)
        this.dataSource.next(param)
    }
}


@Component({
.
.
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
    constructor(private eventProxyService: EventProxyService){}
    ngOnInit() {

        this.eventProxyService.data$.subscribe((param: any) => {
            console.log("in jobs", param)
        })
    }
}
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
Import { EventProxyService } from ‘event-proxy.service’
@NgModule({
    .
    .
    providers: [
        EventProxyService 
    ],
    .
    .
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly. It not only resolves my problem, it increases my understanding of the entire module/component structure. Now I think I need to figure out how to mark this answer as my chosen solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

There are many ways to solve this. One way is indeed to use an injectable service.

I would create a Subject or BehaviorSubject variable (depending on your needs) and use that to update components. Something as followed:

```
service
changeVariable: Subject = new Subject();

component1
this.service.changeVariable.subscribe(
  data => console.log(data)
);

component2
this.service.changeVariable.next('the new value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your service

```
import { BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'
@Injectable()
export class EventProxyService {
    public dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>()
    change(param: any) {
        console.log("in service", param)
        this.dataSource.next(param)
    }
}
```

And instead of subscribing to data$, 
subscribe to dataSource.
Also make sure to keep it as public.